# gsutil upload specific extension file to gcp gcs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

cant upload all file with extension `.css` in the directory or sub directory to GCS bucket

```
gsutil -h "Cache-Control:public,max-age=2628000" -h "Content-Encoding:gzip" cp plugins/**.css gs://cdn.test.example.io/wp-content/plugins
```

response

```
CommandException: No URLs matched: plugins/**.css
```

there are some css files deep in the directory

i want to upload all css file to GCS bucket inside plugin folder or it's any sub-folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)  describe this feature and it works as expected

For my test, I used Cloud Shell with the latest version of gsutil

```
> gsutil -v
gsutil version: 4.52
```

Check your version, and update it to see if that solve your issue

However you can also do this to upload only the file of Plugin directory

```
cd plugins

gsutil -h "Cache-Control:public,max-age=2628000" -h "Content-Encoding:gzip" cp **.css gs://cdn.test.example.io/wp-content/plugins
```

If you want to scan any directory and export the `CSS` files, you can use this command

```
gsutil cp ./**/*.css gs://cdn.test.example.io/wp-content/plugins
```

Comment: thanks for writing answer, first one still giving error `CommandException: No URLs matched: **.css`

Comment: i want o upload all `.css` file anywhere in current directory or it's sub directory.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't in the correct directory when I did my tests! I update my answer